# NavigationMixin with parameters

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am using NavigationMixin to navigate from one lwc to another lwc (app page in a custom tab) like this:

```
navigateToTabPage() {
    // Navigate to a specific CustomTab.
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__navItemPage',
        attributes: {
            apiName: 'TABNAME'
        }
    });
}
```

How can I add some parameters (for example an Id) and how can I handle this parameters in the new component ?

Answer (score 5):

[standard__navItemPage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_page_reference_type) PageReference Type does not have any property other than apiName which is the unique name of the **CustomTab**.  It means you can not pass anything other than that.

You should use **standard__component** PageReference Type.
To make an addressable Lightning web component, embed it in an Aura component that implements the lightning:isUrlAddressable interface.

```
{
    type: 'standard__component',
    attributes: {
        componentName: 'c__MyLightningComponent'
    },
    state: {
        c__counter: '5'
    }
}
```

You can pass any key and value in the state object. The key must include a namespace, and the value must be a string.

Comment: I would also point @Teemo_smr to [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/268907/is-it-possible-to-navigate-to-a-visualforce-page-from-an-lwc/269084#269084) to a previous question that may include some relevant information.

Comment: @sanket kumar is this the only method?

Comment: How to provode a label for subtab that opens up,  to the above code?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a solution going forward--you can also create parameters for your new page via state:

```js
navigateToTabPage() {
    // Navigate to a specific CustomTab.
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__navItemPage',
        attributes: {
            apiName: 'TABNAME'
        },
        state: {
          id: '12345' //must be string
        }
    });
}
```

The new page will then have key-value pairs in the URL as URL parameters so it will look something like this:
https://{salesforceURL}/page?id=12345

On the new page, you can then access this property by inspecting the state property returned from CurrentPageReference (wire adaptor imported from 'lightning/navigation'