# Use data from previous page in Lightning Community with lwc

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, community, navigation

We have a Community made up of 2 pages, using lwc and also Apex (for org queries and API calls). We go from one to the other with Navigation Mixin.

On the first page, we get a lot of data from Apex methods and callouts to external servers.

After navigating to the second page, is there a way to use all the data gathered on the first page, so we don't have to do a second round of callouts to external servers and Apex methods?

Currently, any information from the first page that is needed in the second one is saved to the Local Storage, but we'd like to know if there's another way to store this information in a way that is not so available to the user.

Two things to consider, using standard or custom objects to store this information is not what we're looking for, and also, it's plenty of information, so it's not a parameter that we can add to the URL either.

Any other suggestions are more than welcome!

Thanks,

Comment: Does this answer help you at all? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/299105/navigationmixin-with-parameters

Comment: Not in this case because according to documentation the state property does not work in Experience Builder

Comment: If you can't use the `state` property, local storage, or URL params, I think you might be out of client-side options.  Server-side, you could potentially save JSON content in an attachment/file/note prior to navigating, then have the 2nd page delete the item from the server after loading and parsing the JSON.

Comment: @Matthew Souther which tool did you have in mind for the latter approach you're mentioning?

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of 1) an `@AuraEnabled` Apex method that receives a JSON string and saves the content as a File (`ContentVersion`), returning the randomly-generated file name, then 2) a 2nd `@AuraEnabled` Apex method that receives the file name and returns the JSON string after retrieving, then deleting, the `ContentDocument`.  Or something similar...

Comment: @MatthewSouther That could be a way to go. The thing is it would involve Apex calls and saving data to the org, which we're trying to avoid. I was thinking about something like a persisting Redux Store in React