# Opening URL's stored on record page in Lightning via button

Tags: lightning, subtab-apps

We have a few external URL's stored on Account records that are populated by an internal tool. These are absolute URLS (https'n'all) to the same records in an internal system.  How do I make these addressable in Lightning?  Do I create a small Lightning Component that opens these URL in a Lightning subtab?  Can Lightning even open a seperate browser tab  to open these?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst your question relates to external URLs, it seems clear that you wish to open new tabs that include the Lightning "chrome", including the Salesforce app navigation bar I presume. That means you need:

1. A target page that includes a custom component that:

   1. Gets query parameters from the page that direct its behaviour; e.g. the external URL to be shown.
   2. Uses an iframe to show that external URL within its body; this will require the external site to allow this cross-domain frame ancestor scenario.
2. A custom component you can use in your Account page for each of these URL fields that presents a button that when clicked navigates (in a new tab) to the target page, passing the required query parameter(s), e.g. the external URL from the field.

You'll find some helpful information in this [previous Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/268907/is-it-possible-to-navigate-to-a-visualforce-page-from-an-lwc-with-parameters-and) around passing URL parameters using the [NavigatorMixin](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation) with LWC components.

You'll also want to read about [frame ancestors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors) in case this might bite you.

Comment: Thanks Phil,  I've never even looked at NavigatorMixin before. In my opinion this all complicates things a lot since in classic this would have been solved easily with a custom button that referenced the Account field directly.

Comment: @akarnid this would not have kept the user within the Salesforce Experience though; if you don't need the Salesforce "chrome" (including navigation bar etc.) to be around the target external URL simply open that URL in a new tab. The user is then completely outside the Salesforce Experience but they do see the external page.