# CSFR Errors When Accessing VisualForce Page From Lightning Web Component Even With NavigationMixin

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, docusign, csrf

I've seen many questions on accessing Visualforce pages from LWC, including the following [Is it possible to navigate to a Visualforce page from an LWC with parameters and community compatible](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/268907/is-it-possible-to-navigate-to-a-visualforce-page-from-an-lwc-with-parameters-and) however to date I've still been unable to get this to work.  What I am trying to do is replicate the following URLFOR in a Lignting Web Component

```
{!URLFOR(IF($Site.prefix == '/s','/apex/dfsle__gendocumentgenerator', $Site.Prefix +'/apex/dfsle__gendocumentgenerator'), null, [sId = Opportunity.Id, templateId = 'a201q000001vutgAAA', recordId = Opportunity.Id, title = 'Generate Doc'])}
```

I tried
var urlVal = '/apex/dfsle__gendocumentgenerator';
this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
type: 'standard__webPage',
attributes: {
url: urlVal,
sId: this.recordId,
templateId: this.value,
recordId: this.recordId,
title: 'GenerateDocument'
}
}).then(generatedUrl => {
window.open(generatedUrl);
});

I tried
var urlVal = '/s/apex/dfsle__gendocumentgenerator?sId=' + this.recordId + '&templateId=' + this.value + '&recordId=' + this.recordId + '&title='Generate Document'';

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__webPage',
            attributes: {
                         url: urlVal
                        }
            }, 
            false);
```

I tried
this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
type: 'standard__webPage',
attributes: {
url: urlVal
}
}).then(generatedUrl => {
window.open(generatedUrl);
});

For each of these I get "The link you followed isn’t valid. This page requires a CSRF confirmation token. Report this error to your Salesforce administrator."

Is it correct that using "NavigationMixin" means this should not occur?

Could it be an issue with it being a managed package VF page?

Can I directly implement a URLFOR in LWC?  I note in the answer in the linked question that an Apex PageReference has been returned to help the process?  Would NavigationMixin not eleviate the need for such a requirement?

Thanks in advance for any further pointers on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same solution using an Apex function as per [Is it possible to navigate to a Visualforce page from an LWC with parameters and community compatible](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/268907/is-it-possible-to-navigate-to-a-visualforce-page-from-an-lwc-with-parameters-and) applied.  I had wondered if it could have been done without Apex but I was unable to do so.

Comment: Dude, this is EXACTLY what I was trying to do. Basically execute DocuSign from a LWC for a custom implementation. Thank you!