# lightning message service not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, customer-community, lightning-message-service, lightning-message-channel

I'm using `Lightning message service` to pass message from LWC to another LWC.Both components are custom components used in community pages. The message is not being sent to the other component.

**Publisher**

```
import { publish, MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';
import SCORING from '@salesforce/messageChannel/Scoring__c';
    @wire(MessageContext)
    messageContext;
    msgTest = 'test';

    publishMeasureItems() {
            const payload = { measureItems: this.msgTest };
    
            publish(this.messageContext, SCORING, payload);
        }
    connectedCallback(){
        publishMeasureItems();
    }
```

**Subscriber**

```
@wire(MessageContext)
    messageContext;

    subscription = null;
    measureItems = [];

    // Navigate to fiche nutrition after clicking on back arrow 
    handleArrowClick() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'comm__namedPage',
            attributes: {
                name: 'Programme__c'
            },
        });
    }

    // Encapsulate logic for Lightning message service subscribe and unsubsubscribe
    subscribeToMessageChannel() {
        if (!this.subscription) {
            this.subscription = subscribe(
                this.messageContext,
                SCORING,
                (message) => this.handleMessage(message),
                { scope: APPLICATION_SCOPE }
            );
        }
    }

    unsubscribeToMessageChannel() {
        unsubscribe(this.subscription);
        this.subscription = null;
    }

    // Handler for message received by component
    handleMessage(message) {
        this.measureItems = message.measureItems;
    }

    // Standard lifecycle hooks used to subscribe and unsubsubscribe to the message channel
    connectedCallback() {
        try {
            this.subscribeToMessageChannel();
            console.log('######################' + this.measureItems);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
        this.unsubscribeToMessageChannel();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the components are on different pages. In this case the messaging would not work as it is explained in this Q&A:

[Lightning Message Service doesn't work between community pages](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/363551/lightning-message-service-doesnt-work-between-community-pages)